# Change text color every second

Tags: javascript, loops, colors

I tried to use the code below to change text color to random colors every second but it still didn't work,
Is this the correct script when calling element by className

```
var tx = document.getElementByClassName("this");

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function changeColor(){
  tx.style.color= getRandomColor();
}

setInterval(changeColor,1000);
```

Comment: you get elementS (plural). The name of the function is `getElementsByClassName`, not `getElementByClassName`. The console does spot this error, so keep an eye on it when developing JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: And, let's all agree to [stop using `.getElementsByClassName()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) in the first place, since event delegation really covers its primary use case.

Answer (score 3):

Use `querySelector` instead of `getElementByClassName` or `getElementsByClassName[0]`.

```js
var tx = document.querySelector(".this");

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function changeColor(){
  tx.style.color= getRandomColor();
}

setInterval(changeColor,1000);
```

```html
<p class="this">Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that `getElementByClassName` doesn't exist.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yeah nice observation, I completely missed that!

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I also used it in wix's velo to change text element's colors but it's giving error 'tx.style is undefined' where tx is the variable that stores the element by it's id. Can you help with this

Answer (score 0):

Class selectors returns ElementList you should change your

```js
var tx = document.getElementByClassName("this");
```

to

```js
var tx = document.getElementsByClassName("this")[0];
```

and make sure that `"this"` is an actual class name in your html code.

Comment: [No, no, no, no!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474)

Comment: damn didnt thought about this ;-;